# How to delete extra invisible space from div inside div making it the same height as the parent div?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a simple top navbar with a image on the left side and the buttons on the right side.
Here's the HTML:

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
}

.topnav img {
  height: 4.5rem;
  padding-left: 35px;
}

#nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px 35px 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="./img/logo.png"></img>
  </div>
  <div id="nav">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="products">Products</a>
    <a href="contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="about">About</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, when I inspect #nav, there's [this little invisible space on the bottom](https://i.imgur.com/dD2etm7.png), after the padding.
What did I do wrong or what do I have to do to fix it?

EDIT: new screenshot with the gap identified. It's between the padding (as shown in light green) and the bottom of #topnav

Comment: Can you share demo url?

Comment: Can you set #nav {padding-right:0px;}

Comment: I'm not sure what space you mean, but it's probably the room for the descender below the img. In that case, just add `vertical-align:top;` to `.topnav img`.

Comment: What "little invisible space on the bottom" are you talking about? Your image isn't immediately clear what you're referring to.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear: The "little invisible space on the bottom" is the space between the padding (shown in light green) and the bottom of the .topnav.

New pic: https://i.imgur.com/dD2etm7.png

Comment: Would need to see a reproducible example since yours doesn't have the same issue but a shot in the dark guess would be it's the image on the left pushing the parent height, could try adding height 100% to `#nav` but that's just a guess. PS - `</img>` isn't valid.

Comment: The image is taller than the menu. Decrease the height of the image, increase the padding of the meny, etc

Comment: @ChrisW. You're right. That image is doing something. When I remove it, that little space is gone. I tried to add the height: 100% you suggested, but it didn't do anything. Here's a pen with the code and the same exact image: https://codepen.io/Abernecio/pen/JjdpPPv

Comment: @TemaniAfif Nice, it fixed the issue! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As [@TemaniAfif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif) suggested:

> The image is taller than the menu. Decrease the height of the image, increase the padding of the meny, etc